# Print value at a Fragment Textview

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

Hi I want to show up a SignalStrength value from a Parcelable activity into a fragment.What method should I follow to print it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting parcelable object from intent get the data from intent in fragment using activity reference or through interface.

Comment: Τhank you for the advice,I will try it